# Finding quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group

Let $G = U_{44}, N = \langle |3| \rangle, K = \langle |9| \rangle$.

a) Find $G/ K, G/ N, N/ K, (G/ K)/ (N/ K)$

b) Explain why $(G/ K)/ (N/ K) \cong G/ N $

Comment: What do you mean by $U_{44}$?

Comment: Does it make sense to call $U_{44}$ the group of units in $\mathbb{Z}_{44}$?

Comment: @Moe Yes, it does... **if** you so define it. In spite of being this a rather widespread notation, you better explain your symbols.

Comment: Honestly I'm at a loss of what to try on this one

Answer (score 0):

$U_{44}$ has order $\phi(44)=20$. Actually, $U_{44} \cong U_4 \times U_{11} \cong C_2 \times C_{10}$.

$3$ has order $10$ mod $11$ and so has order $10$ mod $44$.
So, $G/N$ has order $2$ and is $C_2$.

$9$ has order $5$ mod $44$ and mod $11$.
So, $G/K \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

$N/K$ has order $2$ and so is $C_2$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with C$_2$ and $C_{10}$.  Why does their product equal $U_4 \times U_{10}$?

Comment: @Moe. $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: @Moe $U_4 \cong C_2$ and $U_{11} \cong C_{10}$.